# Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2 Messed up After Joining Modifed Server Game

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, cheats

The other day I was playing CODMW2 for PC multiplayer online, the auto-matchup made me join some kind of modified server game. I quit immediately however it seems to have messed up my COD install.

Now when I try to play a game the small map that usually appears in the upper left of the  screen now takes up 1/4 of my screen, some x,y,z coordinates appear in the upper right of the screen, and the cross hairs for my gun(s) have disappeared.

Any idea how I can reset these changes, or do I need to reinstall COD? If I reinstall is there anyway to prevent autojoining to these modified versions of COD?

Comment: This is the PC version?

Comment: ya the PC version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked many times and discussed to death in the Steam forums.

See this thread for details:
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1297234

Comment: Fix 3.1 on that page was the fix for my problem, thanks